# C drive Disk space missing on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My windows drive is 20 GB. I have very few programs installed, consuming not more than 1GB on that drive. But for some reason windows is showing 19 GB used.

I have been searching all over for weeks now. I searched may sites including this blog....all saying it's either the **page file/hibernation file/backup & restore/system protection files** etc. etc. But i am sure in my case it's not any of these above.

i used **TreeSize** Free to scan the drive, it shows only 3.4 GB space is occupied. So what ate my remaining 16 GB???!!!

Need expert suggestion...is it any virus? I have scanned whole PC with the **fully updated NOD32 antivirus** program...no clue...

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot showing what Windows is reporting for the drive size and usage?

Comment: If you say that the entire partition is only 20GB, have you considered Windows7 itself already needs about 16-20GiB of Space?

Comment: I have the screenshot but i am new here and dont know how to upload a screening....can you please help? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: With [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) you can: `Configuration->Options->Display->Show hidden/system files`. With this you will be able to see what is **really** in your hard drive. Also press space and it will show you the consumed space.

Comment: i guess that's the point @ @who.knows

Comment: Run TreeSize as admin: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token to see all files/folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you say that the entire partition is only 20GB, I would say Windows7 is the culprit in this case, since it already needs about 16-20GiB of Space itself.

And that is only when you first install it, due to upgrades and eventually utility programmes, it will grow even larger, so you should consider giving it a little more space.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be any virus, especially after scanning the PC. Please, give it a shot and have a look one more time using cmd command:

```
dir C:\ /AH
```

And see the output. Look for hiberfil.sys, pagefile.sys and such.

Have a look at this [post](http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/16545-where-my-disk-space-going.html#post173315) as well.
There seems to be a System protection thing in Win7 which can build up previous versions of files in case you ever need to restore them.

Comment: i already checked the pagefile and hiberfil. these 2 are consuming only 1.7GB. @AlexanderPoteriachin

Comment: Also system protection is turned on in C drive only, and that too is allowed to use very minimum space. @AlexanderPoteriachin

Comment: Did you check out your Temp directories? Windows stores a lot of files after installation there. Some soft including NOD32 loves to store a bunch of junk in them too. Plus like who.knows said, you may expect that space usage in Win7, see official sys.req (16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)).

Comment: i guess that's right, win7 itself requires a lot of space. And there is a folder named **winsxs** that's consuming around 4 GB. @AlexanderPoteriachin

Comment: Yep. WinSxS (Side-by-side storage) stores all the Windows Features you might ever install and enable. I think, on Win8 and Server 2012 tho you can get rid of majority of it. On Win7, I'm not sure if it's a good idea